# Kill a process run by a specific user

Tags: linux, process, kill

Let's say that I have several users running ''ruby'' processes simultaneously. How do I write a shell command to kill the ''ruby'' process of one particular user? (I'm on CentOS 5.5.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pkill is good good for this:

```
pkill -u particularUser ruby
```

You can use pgrep with this as a test before you run it to see the process name and pid of what will be signaled:

```
pgrep -u particularUser -l ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-u` switch to killall to limit the scope to a single users. So for user abc you could do: `killall -u abc /usr/bin/ruby` (or whatever will match the ruby proccesses)

from `man killall`:

> -u, --user
>   Kill only processes the specified user owns. Command  names  are optional.

Comment: Personally, I much prefer pkill over killall because (a) killall is evil on some Unixes other than Linux and (b) pkill has the pgrep alias that you can use to test that it's going to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

As a worst-case, if you can login or `su -` as the user, you can issue the famed `kill -9 -1` command AS the user to clean up their processes.

Do NOT run as root :)